# How to search a particular word in Oracle table CLOB column that contain a sql statements

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

In this sample data I would like search rows that contain word "100" and "col_2"

Based on sample data rows correct rows are with col1 values as 1,4 and 7

Note: sql_stmt is a `clob` column

```
create table tab1 (col1 number, sql_stmt clob);

insert into tab1(col1, sql_stmt) values(1, 'select col1 from tab1 where col_2=100');
insert into tab1(col1, sql_stmt) values(2, 'select col1 from tab1 where col_2=1000');
insert into tab1(col1, sql_stmt) values(3, 'select col1 from tab1 where col_3=100');

insert into tab1(col1, sql_stmt) values(4, 'select col1 from tab1 where col_2 = 100');
insert into tab1(col1, sql_stmt) values(5, 'select col1 from tab1 where col_2 = 1000');
insert into tab1(col1, sql_stmt) values(6, 'select col1 from tab1 where col_3 = 100');

insert into tab1(col1, sql_stmt) values(7, 'select col1 from tab1 where tab1.col_2 = 100');
insert into tab1(col1, sql_stmt) values(8, 'select col1 from tab1 where tab1.col_2 = 1000');
insert into tab1(col1, sql_stmt) values(9, 'select col1 from tab1 where tab1.col_3 = 100');

commit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query.

select * from tab1 where sql_stmt like '%col_2%=%100'